# Python packaging: build requirements in pyproject.toml VS setup_requires

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pypi, pyproject.toml

In somewhat complex Python `setup.py` configurations, one typically needs other libraries already present in order to execute `setuptools.setup`. In my case, this would be `setuptools>=45.0` and `cython>=0.29`. Now, I have two options to declare these build-time requirements (not to confuse with standard package installation requirements typically found in a `requirements.txt` file) in order to ship this project to PyPI:

1. Manually write the requirements as part of `setup.py` in the `setup_requires` argument:

```py
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup
#...
setup(
    name='bla',
    #...
    setup_requires = ['setuptools>=45.0', 'cython>=0.29'],
)
```

2. Write these requirements into a separate `pyproject.toml` file following [PEP518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/):

```
#pyproject.toml
[build-system]
# Minimum requirements for the build system to execute.
requires = ["setuptools>=45.0", "cython>=0.29"]
```

Are they exchangeable? Which one should be used and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aforementioned PEP was created to address the limitations of the 1st approach that are listed in the [Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#id24) section. [Packaging Python](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) recommends using the 2nd approach.